# calculate the probability of a dog to be cured from syndrome is 0.4, in a sample of 12 dogs, what is the probability of picking 2 dogs are cured?

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

in my midterm exam there was a question: 'calculate the probability of a dog to be cured from syndrome is 0.4, in a sample of 12 dogs, what is the probability of picking 2 dogs are cured?' I answer by applying probability rule: P(C)=0.4, P(D)=1/6, so P(C intersect D)=0.4*1/6=0.067, did i do wrong? Because my friends told me that i can'y use probability rule like that, instead, they use Binomial Distribution by typing syntax BINOM.DIST(2;12;0,4;0) on Excel, please help me i don't understand when shall i use probability rule or binomial distribution. Thanks very much

Comment: They are correct. Each dog has a 40% chance of being cured, and you've taken 12 samples. Can you re-cast this as a coin flipping experiment?

Comment: if it's a coin flipping test then i literally compute the probability of geting 2 heads out of 12 trials but the head face is a bit lighter so only 40% chance to get it, but i don't really carry out 12 trials, i just do 2 (the third trial may get head, the forth and fifth also but we don't know 'cause we just flip 2 times), so is there any difference in the result if i think that way?

Comment: Your description of the coin is correct, however, your flipping process is wrong given your post. Your post says what is the probability of picking 2 cured dogs in a sample of 12 dogs, not "what is the probability that the first two dogs you pick will be cured"....these are different questions. There is no mention of sequential sampling in the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the things that you should always do when you are doubting whether your solutions is correct is to simplify the problem to the extreme so that the answer becomes trivial, and test whether your expression works or not.

For instance, you suspected that the result is $P(C)*\frac{2}{12}$. 
Imagine that the probability of a dog being cured is 1, that means whichever two dogs you choose they will be cured, and hence the answer should have been one, but applying your expression above $P(C)*\frac{2}{12} = 1*\frac{2}{12}= \frac{2}{12}$.

That proves that your expression is incorrect.

Now how should you think about the problem?

First let's restate the problem: You want to calculate the probability of the cases where exactly 2 out of the 12 dogs are cured.

First question to ask is: for a given couple of dogs (D1, D2), what is the probability of this couple to be cured and for all the dogs that are NOT in the couple to be sick? The answer is $0.4^2*0.6^{10}$(2 dogs cured, 10 sick)

Now what we want to calculate is the probability of any of the possible couples in the group to be healthy AND all the other dogs that are not in the couple to be sick (remember we are looking at the probability for having exactly two dogs healthy)

$ result = Probability(only\:dogs\:in\:couple1\:healthy\:OR\: only\:dogs\:in\:couple2\:healthy\:OR\: only\:dogs\:in\:couple3\:healthy ....)$

Note that the case (let's call it A) where only dogs in a couple 1 are healthy is disjoint (can't occur at same time) with the case (let's call it B) where only dogs in couple 2 are healthy...which means P(A OR B) = P(A) + P(B)
so that means that

$$\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
result &= \sum\limits^{every\:couple}Probability(only\:this\:couple\:to\:be\:healthy)\\
&= \sum\limits^{every\:couple}0.4^2*0.6^{10}\\
&= \dbinom{12}{2}*0.4^2*0.6^{10}
\end{split}
\end{equation}$$

solution in $\dbinom{12}{2}*0.4^2*0.6^{10}$ which is in Excel BINOM.DIST(2;12;0,4;0)

Now if you want to calculate the probability of AT MOST 2 dogs being cured, switch the last parameter in Excel form 0 to 1, that will calculate the sum probability of cases where exactly k dogs are healthy from 0 to 2 in your case.

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the answer should be 0.4 * 0.4

Ihab answer would make sense, has pointed out, if the question was: "what is the probability of picking *ONLY* 2 dogs are cured?" Please edit your question if so.

Also,  $\binom{12}{2}$ would make sense, if it is given that the dogs are distinguishable in this example. Please correct that, if so.

Otherwise I would say it should be 0.4 * 0.4